# How to prove this a(n) is bounded above

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have $0<a_1<1$, and $a(n+1)=a(n)+\frac{a(n)^2}{n^2}$ for $n\geq 1$. How can I show $a(n)$ is bounded above.

Comment: Welcome to the math.SE! What have you tried for this problem?

Comment: Hi, since it’s my first time to use this forum, I’m sorry for my question’s format. Thanks for you guys to help me to edit the format. I have proved that a(n) <= n*a(1) by induction, and I also take the reciprocal for both sides, and get some relation between 1/a(n) and 1/a(n+1), but I can’t continue then.

Answer (score 0):

Idea (partial answer) : You have $a_k>0$ for all $k$ and
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{n^2+a_n}$$ hence
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2+a_k}$$
but one has also to show that $\frac{1}{a_1}-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2+a_k} >0$ to finish...

Comment: Yeah, I also get this result but not sure how to prove it larger than 0 when n close to infinity